# $\mathbf{A}$ is unimodular $\Rightarrow$ $\mathbf{A}$ has entry in $\{-1, 0, 1\}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, definition

Is it true that 
$$\mathbf{A}\;\text{is unimodular}\;\Rightarrow\mathbf{A}\;\text{has entry in}\; \{-1, 0,1\}?$$
Also can an unimodular matrix $\mathbf{A}$ has entry in $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: By definition, the entries of a unimodular matrix must be integers. However, they can be other numbers than -1, 0 or 1. Consider [Pascal matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal_matrix), for instances.

Comment: Rather, consider the $1\times1$ minors of the matrix: if the matrix is unimodular, what are their possible determinants?